# redirect to a variable storing awk in bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
cat list.txt
```

`1 apple     4    30     f
2 potato    2    40     v
3 orange    5    10     f
4 grapes   10    8      f`

Script : getlist ::

```
if  [[ "$@" == *[f]* ]] ; then
  awkv1 = $(grep f | awk '{ print $2  $3 }')
else
  awkv1 = $(awk '{ print $2 $4 $5 }')
fi

cat list.txt  | $(awkv1)
```

I have a variable awkv1 that stores value depending on argument 'f'. 
But it is not working . 
Running :: `getlist f`  doesn't do anything.

It should work like this ::
If 'f' is passed in argument then :: `cat list.txt  | grep f | awk '{ print $2  $3 }'`

otherwise ::  `cat list.txt  | awk '{ print $2 $4 $5 }'`

Comment: What if another column matches `f`?  Suppose you have a `fruit` in the second column, but `v` at the end instead of an `f`.

Comment: I want to ask , I have this `awkv1` variable whose value depends on condition.  But redirection  to `awkv1` variable storing awk command , is not working.     `cat list.txt  | $(awkv1)`

Comment: What are you really trying to do? All or most of what I see can probably be done in one simpler call to awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing partial command line in a string variable is error-prone better to use bash arrays.

You can tweak your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# store awk command line in an array
if  [[ "$*" == *f* ]]; then
  awkcmd=(awk '/f/{ print $2, $3 }')
else
  awkcmd=(awk '{ print $2, $4, $5 }')
fi

# execute your awk command
"${awkcmd[@]}" list.txt
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some corrections you need to perform in your script:

1. Remove spaces of `awkv1 = $`
2. Instead of `grep f` use `grep 'f$'`. This approach matches the character `f` only in the last column and avoids fruits with the letter `f`, e.g. *fig*, being matched when the last column ends with `v.`
3. Replace `cat list.txt  | $(awkv1)` by `echo "$awkv1"` since the output of the previous command is already stored in the variable `$awkv1`.

The corrected version of script:

```
if  [[ "$@" == *[f]* ]] ; then
  awkv1=$(grep 'f$' | awk '{ print $2, $3 }')
else
  awkv1=$(awk '{ print $2, $4, $5 }')
fi

echo "$awkv1"
```

You can invoke this script this way: `cat list.txt | getlist f`

Comment: But How would it read data from list.txt.  There is no list.txt file mentioned in your code.

Comment: There is no need to mention `list.txt` inside the script since it can be invoked this way: `cat list.txt | ./getlist f`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do something like:

File: **getlist**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "f" ]; then
    awk '$5=="f"{print $2,$3}' list.txt
else
    awk '{print $2,$4,$5}' list.txt
fi
```

If this file is executable, you can call it like:

```
$ ./getlist f
apple 4
orange 5
grapes 10
$ ./getlist
apple 30 f
potato 40 v
orange 10 f
grapes 8 f
$
```

Or if you want to specify the search value on the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" ]; then
    awk -v t="$1" '$5==t{print $2,$3}' list.txt
else
    awk '{print $2,$4,$5}' list.txt
fi
```

This way, you can list fields labelled `f` or `v`:

```
$ ./getlist
apple 30 f
potato 40 v
orange 10 f
grapes 8 f
$ ./getlist f
apple 4
orange 5
grapes 10
$ ./getlist v
potato 2
$
```

Comment: Nice approach! It is very readable and more comprehensive this way.

Comment: Yes, There are many approaches to do this.  But I wanted to do this using redirection to a variable  having awk command .